# Should C compilers immediately free "further unused" memories?

Tags: c, gcc, visual-c++, clang, ram

Context: while compiling some C code compilers may show high RAM consumption. Preliminary investigation shows that (at least some) C compilers do not immediately free "further unused" memories: despite that such (previously allocated) memories are not used anymore, they are still kept in the RAM. The C compiler continues processing the C code, allocating more memories in the RAM, until it reaches OOM (out of memory).

The core question: should C compilers immediately free "further unused" memories?

Rationale:

1. Efficient RAM utilization: no need of mem_X anymore => free mem_X to let other processes (itself including) to use mem_X.
2. Ability to compile the "RAM demanding" C code.

---

UPD20210825. I've memory-profiled some C compiler and have found that it keeps in RAM "C preprocessor data", in particular:

- macro table (memory pool for macros);
- scanner token objects (memory pool for tokens and for lists).

At certain point X in the middle-end (after the IR is built) these objects seem not needed anymore and, hence, can be freed. (However, now these objects are kept in RAM until a point X+1.) The benefit is seen on "preprocessor-heavy" C programs. Example: "preprocessor-heavy" C program using "ad hoc polymorphism" implemented via C preprocessor (by using a set of macros it progressively implements all the needed "machinery" to support a common interface for an arbitrary (and supported) set of individually specified types). The number of "polymorphic" entries is ~50k * 12 = ~600k (yes, it does not say anything). Results:

- before fix: at point X C compiler keeps in RAM ~1.5GB of unused "C preprocessor data";
- after fix: at point X C compiler frees from RAM ~1.5GB of unused "C preprocessor data", hence, letting OS processes (itself including) to use these ~1.5GB.

Comment: Are you *sure* that the compilers doesn't free the memory? Or perhaps it's a false positive because the operating system still keeps free pages mapped to the compiler process (which is known to happen)?

Comment: Needed for symbol table? Needed by debugger? It must be possible to set a break or watch point when a function isn't active, or data is out of scope.

Comment: Several C compilers are open source (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)...): so you are allowed to improve them. And most computers used by developers are quite powerful (since the cost of a programmer is higher than the cost of the computer he/she needs to use). BTW, GCC has its own garbage collector, and you could write a C compiler in [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org/) starting from [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/)

Comment: 1.  Memory allocation and retention isn't a problem until it is.  Don't solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: 2.  The OS automatically frees any memory allocated when the process running the compiler exits.

Comment: Your question is not clear: do you want C compiler to free memory allocated by the C program, or to clear memory allocated by the compiler itself?

Comment: By now, you should know better than to enter a question with missing information. You have done “preliminary investigation.” So show data from that investigation. Show a sample compilation where the compiler uses memory and does not not free it when it could. State the compiler. Show how you know it has memory it has not freed and does not use again.

Comment: And state why you think there could be any basis for whether a compiler should free memory. Do you think there might be something in the C standard about that? Some other specification. Obviously you know it would be a good thing for any program to release memory it does not benefit from. So there is no point in asking that as a question. You must be asking something else, whether there is some rule or specification about how a compiler ought to behave in this regard. Why do you think such a rule might exist? What are you actually asking about?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for the comments! For the moment see UPD20210825.

Comment: @WeatherVane _Needed for symbol table?_ It turned out that C preprocessor tables take much data, which at certain point X can be freed. See UPD20210825.

Comment: @pmor How do you know it **isn't** freed, but remains in memory simply because the OS doesn't return heap memory to the OS?

Comment: Unspecified compiler, compiling unspecified code, with unspecified options, profiled in an unspecified way with and without an unspecified patch. I feel a little more clarity might still be beneficial.

Comment: @AndrewHenle _How do you know it isn't freed_: because in the code the `free` is executed at the point `N+1`, while it can (should) be executed at the point `N`. Starting from the point `N` the C preprocessor data is not needed anymore, and, hence, can be freed.

Comment: @Useless The question is general, not about a specific implementation. I think that if an allocated memory X is not needed after point N, then it is rational to free X at the point N+1.

Comment: @pmor *because in the code the free is executed at the point N+1, while it can (should) be executed at the point N*  **What** code? You've yet to demonstrate any concrete case where 1) the memory wasn't actually freed nor 2) that it could be freed.  And this is all for an ephemeral process that in almost all cases is going to exit and free all its memory anyway in just a few tenths of a second - at most.  Boogeymen and windmills are coming to my  mind...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know where you get your analysis from. Most parts like the abstract syntax tree is kept because it is used in all different passes.

It might be that some, especially simple compilers don't free stuff because it's not considered necessary for a C compiler. It's a one shot compilation unit operation and than the process ends.

Of course if you build a compiler library like tinycc did you need to free everything, but even this might happen within a final custom heap clearance at the end of the compilation run.

I have not seen this ever be a problem in real world. But i don't do embedded stuff where a lack of resources can be something to worry.

Answer (score -2):

> allocating more memories in the RAM, until it reaches OOM (out of
> memory).

None of the compilers I use ever run out of memory. Please give an example of such behaviour.

If you are an Arduino user and think about the code which will not fit into the memory - it is not the problem of the compiler, only the programmer.

Comment: *None of the compilers I use ever run out of memory* You need to try harder.  ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle wonderful comment.